# SearchableByName Interface keeps returning null

Tags: java, search, interface

My goal is to search a multi-tree structure to see which item matches the name I am looking for. I am doing this by implementing an interface I made named SearchByName in every class I need to search in.

The way my data is contained is that I have an ArrayList called parties comprised of Party objects that each have a name in an object called the cave, each Party has an ArrayList called members comprised of Creature objects that each have a name, and each creature has an ArrayList called artifacts comprised of Artifact objects that each posses a name;

Every time I search the search returns null even when there should be a match.

This is my code for performing the search:

```
for ( Party p : SorcerersCave.theCave.parties ){
                SearchableByName foundItem = p.searchByName( name );
                if ( foundItem != null ) {
                    GenerateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "\t" + foundItem );
                } else {
                    GenerateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "Item NOT FOUND" );
                }
                break;
            }
```

This is the interface I am implementing:

```
interface SearchableByName {
public SearchableByName searchByName (String name );
public String getName();
```

}

this is the interface being implemented in Party:

```
public SearchableByName searchByName ( String n ) {
    if ( getName() == n ) {
        return this;
    } else {
        for ( Creature c : members ) {
            SearchableByName found = c.searchByName( n );
            if ( found != null ) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the interface being implemented in Creature:

```
public SearchableByName searchByName ( String n ) {
    if ( getName() == n ) {
        return this;
    } else {
        for ( Artifact a : artifacts ) {
            SearchableByName found = a.searchByName( n );
            if ( found !=null ) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And finally I implement the interface in Artifact:

```
public SearchableByName searchByName ( String n ) {
    return ( getName() == n ) ? this : null;
}
```

This is my first time trying to searching into the classes rather than do everything at the top level.

Comment: `if ( getName() == n )` is your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below lines :

```
getName().equals(n);
```

However make sure that getName is never null, if it can be null, put a null check.